# How do I reset Page life cycle from code behind?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a web page that is meant to be a product view for a computer. I have a div next to the product photo that contains the product information. The div is runat="server" and when the user selects a 'customize' button within the div, I have C# in the code behind button event handler that erases the current product information in the div and replaces it with drop down menus for the customization options.

I want to have a "Cancel Customization" button that allows the user to stop customizing and go back to the original product view page. I have tried using Response.Redirect("CurrentPageUrl"); but because I am redirecting to the page I am currently on, I guess it's a postback and not a full life cycle reset. The result is that the page reloads with the div just empty. What I really want to do is reset the page life cycle somehow, so it is as if the 'Customize' button was never clicked and the original page code, including the product info, on the server is completely reinitialized. I have looked around for how to do this but everywhere just seems to recommend Response.Redirect() which as I have said does not produce the desired behavior.

I realize I could just reinsert all of the original product information from the original page but this seems like a lot of code and I figure there must be a way to just re-initialize the Page?

Summary:

Page initializes with div filled with Product Info.

Customize button is clicked, button handler in C# code behind removes contents of div and replaces it with customization options.

desired behavior: 'Cancel customization' button is clicked, page is reloaded so product info is now back in div.

current behavior: 'Cancel customization' button is clicked, Response.Redirect("CurrentPageUrl") is called, page posts back and div is now empty.

I will be checking this post very often for the first few days so please don't hesitate to ask for more info I'll get back to you quickly. I apologize in advance if this question has already been asked, I did spend quite a bit of time looking for answers on S.O before posting this and as I said all I could find were recommendations for Response.Redirect() which is not what I'm looking for. I am developing the site using VS2019 ASP.NET framework web forms if that makes a difference.
Thanks for any answers!

Comment: Please post your code with your question

Comment: I have a lot of very complex code for this page so I went with explaining my code logic as opposed to posting the large code body itself. Are there specific functional modules you wish to see? if so please request them and I will add to the question.

Comment: Why not just have two divs - hide or show one or the other - that way you don't have to think about, or worry about which one, and what has occurred. You can keep a status flag in view state or session that controls which one to display, and also of course in code check the value to use that custom information or not. So, this would 100% eliminate the need to "revert" back to some default display - just hide one div, and display the other one in code behind depending on which one you wish to display.

Comment: That is a good idea and I may go with that just to get my site functional (although I am loath too add all of the code for the multiple divs in my code behind) but I am still curious now how to reset the page lifecycle from the code behind. There must be some way to do this no? Edit: I just realized I could do what you are describing with javaScript fairly easily actually so maybe not as difficult as I was thinking

Comment: You don't have to show/hide a whole bunch of divs - but just drop + wrap the two sections each in their own div. Hiding that one div will hide/show everything inside of that section. The only issue is the status of the div does not always persist. (and often it does). So, add a "id" and a "runat=server" to the div. Now you can access and use that div freely in code behind - including a hide/show. And in fact do NOT use visible for this, but style="display:none" (to hide) or style="display:normal" to show. (the reason of course is using visible means the html is not sent to client side).